# Tinyproxy to redirect http traffic to https

Tags: http, https, http-proxy, tinyproxy

I'm attempting to redirect all http traffic towards https traffic. I currently have stunnel listening on port 443 which does it's job well. I have now installed Tinyproxy which I want to listen on port 80 and redirect.

I found this little jewel [config](http://distro.ibiblio.org/tinycorelinux/3.x/tcz/src/tinyproxy/tinyproxy.conf). I unfortunately do not know how to configure my own config to redirect. How may i put it, the documentation on the web is lacking to explain such a simple task.

Comment: Why are you using stunnel?  if you have another webserver or proxy listening on the end of what stunnel points to, then this might be able to do the redirect without using tproxy.

Comment: @Matt Currently got a node instance running in a docker container on the "otherside".

Comment: @Matt I do know it is possible in node to redirect, I would however like to abstract this away into it's own container, giving me less headaches in my node code.

Comment: Ahh, ok that makes some sense.  I'm not really familar with tinyproxy.  I use nginx as a proxy for both http/http proxying with docker containers.

Comment: @Matt I normally use HAProxy for this however HAProxy in this case seems overkill as I don't really need a load balancer. If I want load balancing with Docker I'd use Rancher, which needs it's own server, which is pretty overkill again.

Comment: @Matt Tbh, I don't even know if Tinyproxy can redirect.

Comment: True, but sometimes what you think is overkill actually isn't.  haproxy is actually rather light on resources.  Actually looking at tinyproxy, it makes me wonder why youre also using stunnel.  One problem with stunnel appart from being slow is last I checked you couldn't add headers for the real IP's.  So if you have backend services that need those you're out of luck.

Comment: Could you describe in a little more detail, what you want to achieve?